# Regex and (char)30 How can I define

Tags: c#, regex, search

I have a code. I am using Regex.

```
string s = "1-2-3-4-5" (Instead of "-" there is ctr + Shift + "-" in Office Word)
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d*-\d*-\d*-\d*-\d*");
            WordsCount = regex.Matches(s).Count;
```

There is a char[30] (ASCII-record separator) instead of "-". How can I define my search?
I need to do something like this: `(@"\d*-|char(30)\d*-|char(30)\d*-|char(30)\d*-|char(30)\d*");`

Comment: Could you please update your question? It is not clear to me, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am dealing with Office Word document. I have the Word document content in a string. And I am searching there  numbers like 3-2-1-123-15. But sometimes instead of "-"(which is in ASCII (char)45) we are using (char)30 which looks the same in word document but not in the string. So I would like to find also the numbers with record separator nr 30 http://www.asciitable.com/. But right now I cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
(@"\d*(-|\036)\d*(-|\036)\d*(-|\036)\d*(-|\036)\d*");
```

Thanks.